# Как отлаживать JS в VS2017?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Если ставить точки останова в скрипте, то при запуске проекта они становятся белыми и пишется, что они недостижимы, однако, на выражения Razor все прекрасно ставится.

Помню, что в 2013 VS все работало из коробки.

Подскажите, что нужно для дебага?

Comment: отладка скриптов в VS 2017 поддерживается в хроме . При запуске приложения браузер прямо об этом говорит перед открытием стартовой страницы приложения `asp.net-mvc`

Comment: @Eikhner, я как раз в хроме запускаю. Однако точки останова, ругаются на недостежимость. Или вы имеет в виду прямо в Chrome дебажить скрипты?

Comment: @iluxa1810  могу вечером попробовать что покажет у меня ...

Answer (score 2):

**В настройках Visual Studio 2017 активируйте чекбокс:**

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)

*Обратите внимание, что отладка возможна только для отдельных .js(.ts) файлов, отладка скриптов, внедренных в .cshtml, не поддерживается.*

Если, несмотря на активный чекбокс «Enable JavaScript Debugging...», брекпойнт все равно не срабатывает, попробуйте следующее:

- Переинициализируйте (снимите чекбокс / закройте VS / поставь снова)
  чекбокс «Enable JavaScript Debugging...»
- Запустите студию под аккаунтом администратора.

Answer (score 0):

Открываешь консоль разработчика в Chrome на клавишу `F12`, далее выбираешь `Sources` находишь свой скрипт, ставишь breakpoint и на клавишу `F11` делаешь шаги.

Подробнее: https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Надеюсь помог